# Why does theano conv2d add empty dimension?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, theano

I am playing around with some simple Theano code, and I ran into the following:

```
import numpy
import theano
from theano import tensor
from theano.tensor.signal.conv import conv2d

m = tensor.fmatrix()
w = numpy.ones([10,1], dtype=numpy.float32)
c = conv2d(m,w)
f = theano.function([m], c)
print f(numpy.ones([100,100], dtype=numpy.float32)).shape
```

Result:
(1, 91, 100)

The result of a 2d convolution of 2d inputs is expected to be 2d, but it is actually 3d.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docstring of `conv2d` says *signal.conv.conv2d performs a basic 2D convolution of the input with the
given **filters**.* (note the plural)

You could pass it **several** filters and it will return the convolutions with all of those. Try e.g.

```
c = conv2d(m,np.array([w, w, w]))
f = theano.function([m], c)
print f(numpy.ones([100,100], dtype=numpy.float32)).shape  # outputs (3, 91, 100)
```

So it seems that by default it will add a degenerate axis if you only pass 1 filter (probably because it adds this axis internally to your filter if you didn't pass it in that way yourself. In other words, it doesn't keep track of the input shape in order to return something that corresponds. Looks like a design choice more than anything else.)

Comment: Nice catch!  This is a bit of a mis-feature though...  kinda hard to chain convolutions.

Comment: The function is designed to take several images and several filters and convolve all the images with all the filters. It is not sequential application, it is just all possible combinations. However, I think it is not intended to add the empty axis at the beginning, at least according to the [docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/conv.html) where the return shape is stated as being `tensor of filtered images, with shape ([number images,] [number filters,] image height, image width)`, so the two front axes should actually disappear if not needed ...

Comment: I just made a PR to change this to return 2d tensor: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/1891

Comment: That was fast! Thanks!